# Do not show animations on C3.js Donut chart

Tags: javascript, animation, d3.js, c3.js

I'm having some trouble turning off the animation with C3.js. Is it possible to remove animations when mouse over point on C3.js donut chart?

I have duration set to 0, but it does not work - when mouse over chart, animation is still made.

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/4ff8vnx4/1/

This is my code:

```
var chartDonut1 = c3.generate({
  bindto: "#chart1",
  data: {
            type: 'donut',
            json: [
                {"Parfait": 190},
                {"Bien": 120},
                {"Trop court": 32},
                {"Trop long": 22}
            ],
            keys: {
                value: ['Parfait', 'Bien', 'Trop court', 'Trop long']
            },
            names: {
                'Parfait': 'Parfait (entre 50 \340 60 car.)',
                'Bien': 'Bien (entre 40 \340 49 ou  61 \340 69 car.)',
                'Trop court': 'Trop court (inf\351rieur \340 40 car.)',
                'Trop long': 'Trop long (sup\351rieur \340 79 car.)'            
            }
  },
  transition:  {duration: 0}
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You should take a look at the [reference guide](http://c3js.org/reference.html#interaction-enabled) of C3.js. What you want is to disable the interaction. You can achieve this by adding the following snippet to the configuration object.

```
interaction: {
    enabled: false
}
```

Comment: When this option is set to false, all interactions (showing/hiding tooltip, selection, mouse events, etc) are disable. I want to disable animation, not interaction, especially showing/hiding tooltip.

Comment: @LeMoussel This is not possible. You can either enable or disable the interaction but not only disable to animation.

Answer (score 1):

Partial disable animation with `expand` option.

```
donut: {
    expand: false
}
```

Updated my example: https://jsfiddle.net/4ff8vnx4/7/